# Selectively applying user ID in WHERE clause to entries

Tags: php, mysql

I been going back and forth with IF and CASE and a whole lot of other suggestions found elsewhere trying to figure out how to filter out certain entries based on category and user ID. Assume that a table `user_posts` contains posts made by a lot of users. I want to get results restricted to the `user_ID`='MIRA76' for posts that are in categories 'CAT_64' or 'CAT_106'. However, I still want to get results by other users from other categories.

TABLE `user_posts`

```
+----------+--------------+----------+-----------------+
| post_ID  | category_ID  | user_ID  |     content     |
+----------+--------------+----------+-----------------+
| 456FQ    | CAT_64       | MEK90    | TEXTUAL CONTENT |
| 754GD    | CAT_21       | MEK90    | TEXTUAL CONTENT |
| 616CZ    | CAT_106      | MIRA76   | TEXTUAL CONTENT |
| 714PA    | CAT_64       | MIRA76   | TEXTUAL CONTENT |
| 554WU    | CAT_26       | RON32    | TEXTUAL CONTENT |
| 451YD    | CAT_41       | RON32    | TEXTUAL CONTENT |
| 783TD    | CAT_21       | MIRA76   | TEXTUAL CONTENT |
| 156GL    | CAT_11       | MEK90    | TEXTUAL CONTENT |
| 274HD    | CAT_11       | HOM92    | TEXTUAL CONTENT |
+----------+--------------+----------+-----------------+
```

In the example entries, for categories 'CAT_64' and 'CAT_106' only those by the `user_ID` 'MIRA76' is taken, but for other categories there is no such restriction. How do I go about doing this? Here those other than the first one are the ideal results.

Comment: 4 answers appeared while I was still writing mine, I need to type faster

Answer (score 1):

you can use `WHERE` function to limit your query results **documentation** [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/where-optimizations.html)

so you can use something like

```
WHERE user_ID='MIRA76' AND (category_id = 'CAT_64' OR category_id = 'CAT_106')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM user_posts
WHERE (user_ID = 'MIRA76' AND category_ID IN('CAT_64','CAT_106')) 
       OR user_ID != 'MIRA76'
```

### Update

Now that I've read your post *very* carefully and have applied an assumption too, it seems that you don't want *other uses'* posts that are in `CAT_64` and `CAT_106`. Is that right? If yes then try this query

```
SELECT * 
FROM user_posts
WHERE (user_ID  = 'MIRA76' AND category_ID IN('CAT_64','CAT_106')) 
   OR (user_ID != 'MIRA76' AND category_ID NOT IN('CAT_64','CAT_106'))
```

Comment: Yes you assumed right, after seeing your post I decided to use `WHERE category_ID IN ('CAT_64','CAT_106') AND user_ID = 'MIRA76' OR category_ID NOT IN ('CAT_64','CAT_106')` - this seems to do what I want.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options here:

You could split this into two queries - and join the output e.g. Select the restricted user_id, then combine with the other query results (presumably excluding the previously selected).

OR

You could look at using conditional statements in your WHERE clause, e.g. CASE, OR, AND...

If you post the code you have already tried - maybe i can be a bit more specific in helping.